# Swift : HttpRequest works on Simulator but not on Device (iPhone 11)

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlrequest, urlsession

I have an Authentication Manager that send SignIn and SignUp request. Code works good on simulator and fetch data from database but not working on device. On device It gives http 500 error. I check the textfields before sending the request and they seem fine.

Any suggestions to solve this issue ?

```
func performSignIn(email: String, password: String){
    //1. Create URL
    if let url = URL(string: Constants.signInURL){
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        //Request Body
        var body = [String : Any]()
        body["user"] = ["email": email,
                        "password": password]
                
        do {
            request.httpBody  = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: [])
            
        } catch {
            print("JSON serialization failed:  \(error)")
            
        }
        // Change the URLRequest to a POST request
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        //Need to tell that request has json in body.
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        //2. Create URLSession
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        //3. Give Session a task
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    delegate?.failedWithError(error: error!)
                    return
                }
                
            }
            if let safeData = data{
                if let signInResponse = parseJSON(safeData){
                    //Who has the delegate run signInSuccess method
                    delegate?.signInSuccess(signInResponse)
                }
            }

        }
        //4. Start Task
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: A 500 error generally means that the request was received but the server crashed in the processing of it. That is frequently a combination of a incorrectly formed request and the server’s not handling that error case correctly. What’s curious is that if this was a problem, you’d expect the same code on the simulator to work on the device. The other common source of device vs simulator problem (using `localhost` or the equivalent in your URL) wouldn’t result in 500 error. But there’s not enough here to diagnose the problem.

Comment: By the way, completely unrelated to your problem, we should warn you that this code will cause slow memory leak. If create your own session, `let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)`, then you must call `session.finishAndInvalidate()` after starting the task. Or move the instantiation of the session outside this method and make sure you instantiate it once and only once, reusing it for every new request. Or, alternatively, if you’re not performing any custom configuration of the session, you might as well (re)use the shared instance `let session = URLSession.shared`.

Comment: @Rob First thank you for the advice about memory handling. For the other issue; I am not using a localhost url for http request. And I am just using the same login page for taking user email and password with using UITextField. But it is still not working on device. 
I wonder when I get input with using real device is there any additional things (like settings) to do before sending to the server ?

Comment: No, there are no special device specific settings for `URLSession`. There are obviously network-related issues in edge cases (e.g. is server is running on `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` may work on simulator, but wouldn't on device; if server is behind on some VPN; if host name is configured in macOS `/etc/hosts`; etc.). But these are all edge cases. And, again, 500 error suggests that the problem is not in the connecting, but the server's inability to process the request, e.g., malformed request. But there is no magical `URLSession` setting that would work on simulator and not a device.

Comment: I would suggest that you create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because until we can verify/reproduce the problem, we're unlikely to be able to help you solve the problem. I would also suggest that you look at the body of the response associated with the response, because sometimes there are plaintext messages describing why the server failed. Sometimes production servers don't reveal details in the body of the response, but development servers often do. Or look at the error logs on the server. But there is not enough here for us to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @Rob Thank you for your help. I check the server logs and it seems like it rejects my request because of the location. I let the backend people know about the issue. Once they figure out localization thing I think it will solve my problem.